# Get data from onNext in Retrofit rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

In here list (in part list.get(9) ) is a String ArrayList. Im trying to get all username from users and add it to list then show 10th name in a textview.

When i run the app, it throws errors in the image i have linked below, error is index out of bound in textView.setText(list.get(9)) . But it work when i comment this line, and set text for my textview by using button onclick.

Here is the api in my example. 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init api
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    btnOk = findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    myAPI = retrofit.create(IMyAPI.class);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.show);

    //fetchData()

    fetchUserData();

    textView.setText(list.get(9));
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText(list.get(9));
        }
    });

}

private void fetchUserData() {
    myAPI.getUsers()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ArrayList<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<User> users) {
                    String usName ;
                    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
                        usName = posts.get(i).getUsername();
                        list.add(usName);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });

}
```

[Error in line textView.settext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks5SX.png)

Comment: What do you mean by outside of  `onNext`?

Comment: Can you share your exception stack trace as well?

Comment: @BachVu So sorry guys, this is the first time i have asked in stackoverflow. I have edited my post to make it easier to understand. Please check it again, thank you.

Comment: @raxerz sorry guys, this is the first time i have asked in stackoverflow. I have edited my post to make it easier to understand. Please check it again, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code that could cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I'll put some comments in your code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init api
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    btnOk = findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    myAPI = retrofit.create(IMyAPI.class);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.show);

    fetchUserData();


    // this line should be removed cause you didn't get yet the result of fetchUserData(). Instead you should do this on the onNext method.
    // textView.setText(list.get(9)); 

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Before accessing the list, you must ensure your list contains at least 9 elements. Otherwise it could crash.
            // textView.setText(list.get(9));

            // This would be the correct way
            if (list != null && list.size > 9) {
               textView.setText(list.get(9));
            }
        }
    });

}

private void fetchUserData() {
    myAPI.getUsers()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ArrayList<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<User> users) {
                    String usName ;
                    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
                        usName = posts.get(i).getUsername();
                        list.add(usName);
                    }
                    // This is the place where you are safe to access the users list, so any View component you want to update with the users list should be done here.
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });

}
```

Remember that you're using Rx to make an `asynchronous` call, you should wait the `onNext` method to be called before doing any operating with the result.

Comment: Thank you, i understand the problem now, but i want to access the user list from onCreate. Is there any chance to do this or it just not possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to access it in the onCreate? It is not possible cause it depends mainly on the network speed. You should show a `loading` while you retrieve the data from the endpoint.

Comment: You must do it in the onNext cause is the only place where you ensure that the data is received. You will not have a consistent behavior if you access the list in the onCreate cause the endpoint could have answered or not. The only place you can ensure it has answered is the onNext.

Comment: Thank you, I've been thinking about this for long time. Green check for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is that `myAPI.getUsers()` is run in `io` thread which takes time to complete and fill the `list` with username. On the other hand, `textView.setText(list.get(9));` is triggered immediately. Therefore, the correct flow is to put `textView.setText(list.get(9));` in `onNext` or `onComplete`, these methods will be triggered when `myAPI.getUsers()` finishes

Comment: Oh, thanks you, i get it now but is there any ways that i can use ArrayList<User> users in onCreate. I really want to get that list and use separate from OnNext()

Answer (score 0):

your calling  `textView.setText(list.get(9));` in your `onCreate` method while `list` is still empty which causes `IndexOutOfBoundsException` . Remove it form `onCreate` and put it in the `onNext` method:

```
public void onNext(ArrayList<User> users) {
     String usName ;
     for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
         usName = posts.get(i).getUsername();
         list.add(usName);
     }
     textView.setText(list.get(9));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know that calling textView.setText(list.get(9)); in onNext will work, but what i want is using the ArrayList<User> users in onCreate. I don't want to do everything in onNext. I use for loop to copy this Array into new array called list but it not working